# Variable Month mmm and Append to static text Field in SQL select Reporting design Studio 2005

Tags: reporting-services, reportingservices-2005, qlikview

I have a Budget table with field names "SSBJAN", "SSBFEB", "SSMAR", etc for the year

My select query which works ok below, I currently change manually "SSBMAY" each month:

```
SELECT  SADIVO AS Division, SAWHSL AS Location, SSBMAY as BudgetSales, 
FROM BBSCDTA.SA04WH
```

I wish this to pickup from `Month(Today())` with the current Month 'mmm' so I can append it to SSB so it auto selects current month from table.

Below I have created this in QlikView coding but am not able to get this working in Report Designer SQL.

My code for Qlikview

```
Let Today='03/05/2012';
  let CalBud1=Upper(Month(Today()));
    let SSB=Upper('SSB');
let vCalBud=SSB&CalBud1;
```

This returns "SSBMAY" and next month it returns "SSBJUN"

Comment: What database system are you using? Microsoft SQL?
(Looks like your first query was edited. The syntax you posted seems incorrect, especially with the extra comma after BudgetSales.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you want the query for T-SQL (Microsoft's dialect of SQL)

```
SELECT
  SADIVO AS Division,
  SAWHSL AS Location,
  CASE MONTH(GETDATE())
   WHEN 1 THEN SSBJAN
   WHEN 2 THEN SSBFEB
   WHEN 3 THEN SSBMAR
   WHEN 4 THEN SSBAPR
   WHEN 5 THEN SSBMAY
   WHEN 6 THEN SSBJUN
   WHEN 7 THEN SSBJUL
   WHEN 8 THEN SSBAUG
   WHEN 9 THEN SSBSEP
   WHEN 10 THEN SSBOCT
   WHEN 11 THEN SSBNOV
   WHEN 12 THEN SSBDEC
   END as BudgetSales 
FROM BBSCDTA.SA04WH
```

Comment: You can also use the substring. The query will look like this Select SADIVO AS Division, SAWHSL AS Location,'SSB'+UPPER(SUBSTRING(DateName(Month,GetDate()),1,3)) AS BudgetSales FROM BBSCDTA.SA04WH I am not sure about his database that's why I am posting it here as a sugestion.

Comment: Hi Guys sorry for delay Have been off Sick, Jamie thanks for your example it worked in SSRS 2005 I tried M.C.Rohiths code but it returns SSBMAY as the data not the actual table field dollar amount.

Comment: Its my fault for not explaing i am pulling data straight from AS400 table through DB2 connect thanks agian Guys regards Peter